# Unterschied zwischen Thesenpapier, Handout, Handzettel, Tischvorlage und Handreichung

Tags: synonym, anglicism

Auf der Suche nach einem deutschen Wort für den Anglizismus "Handout" bin ich auf die Stichworte "Thesenpapier", "Handreichung", "Handzettel" und "Tischvorlage" gestoßen. Mich würde interessieren, wo die feinen Unterschiede zwischen den Begriffen liegen.

Das Wort "Handout", für das ich ein deutsches Synonym suche, kenne ich vor allem aus dem Zusammenhang, dass es ein Dokument beschreibt, das die wichtigsten Inhalte eines Vortrages auf einer oder wenigen Seiten zusammenfasst (evtl. auch mit Bildern, Graphiken oder Formeln).

"Handreichung" empfinde ich als relativ wohlklingende Alternative, allerdings habe ich den Eindruck, dass hier eher ein längeres Dokument gemeint sein könnte.

"Handzettel" hat wegen des Worts "zettel" für mich einen etwas abwertenden Charakter (d.h. etwas, das man mal kurz anschaut und dann wegwirft). Allerdings scheint sich dieser Ausdruck auf ein kürzeres Dokument zu beziehen.

Bei "Thesenpapier" habe ich das Gefühl, dass es streng genommen keine Bilder und Graphiken enthält. Wenn der Vortrag keine "Thesen" enthält, sondern nur Informationen, erscheint es mir auch unpassend.

Gibt es noch ein passenderes deutsches Wort, das den Anglizismus "Handout" im oben beschriebenen Gebrauch am besten erfasst?

Comment: Und was meinst Du, passiert mit den meisten Handouts? Rahmen sich die Zuhörer das später ein?

Answer (score 5):

Ich würde es so sehen:

**Handreichung:** Überhaupt kein "Handout". "Handreichung" nennt man - vor allem in Pädagogenkreisen - schriftliches Material, das in irgend einer Form bei der Arbeit (hier typischerweise: dem Lehren) helfen soll. Außerhalb der Pädagogik ist mir das Wort bisher noch nicht begegnet.

**Tischvorlage:** Das Wort wird besonders in bürokratischen Zusammenhängen verwendet, sehr häufig in Stadtverwaltungen, Gemeinderräten, Parlamenten. Es bezeichnet dann schriftliches Material, das Mitgliedern eines Gremiums bei einer Sitzung auf den Tisch gelegt (oder oft auch vorher zur Lektüre zugeschickt) wird. Ein Handout in einem Uni-Seminar als Tischvorlage zu bezeichnen, wäre technisch zwar möglich, klänge aber gestelzt. Das Wort hat seinen Sitz einfach in einem anderen Winkel der Gesellschaft.

**Handzettel:** Hat für mein Empfinden mit "Handout" nichts zu tun. Ich vermute, die Urbedeutung ist eigentlich wie Flugblatt: etwas, was man jemandem schnell in die Hand drückt, zu Werbezwecken. Aber es kann natürlich sein, dass andere Leute und Kreise das Wort noch anders verwenden.

**Thesenpapier:** nicht eigentlich ein "Handout"; ein Thesenpapier stellt in schriftlicher Form Thesen zu einem Thema zusammen. Wie dieses Papier dann verbreitet wird, darüber ist mit dem Wort "Thesenpapier" noch nichts gesagt. Natürlich kann man ein Thesenpapier schreiben, es ausdrucken, zusammenheften und dann im Seminar an die Mitstudenten austeilen. Dann ist das Thesenpapier ein Handout geworden.

**Andere Wörter für Handout:** Wie wäre es mit

- Unterlagen?
- Sitzungsunterlagen? - Beides natürlich v.a. wenn es um eine Sitzung geht, nicht um einen Vortrag, was ja deine eigentliche Frage ist.
- Fresszettel? - Wird wohl manchmal verwendet für sehr knappe Handouts; ich vermute, es bezeichnet ursprünglich einen Einkaufszettel. Nur in extrem legerer Kommunikation verwendbar.
- Merkzettel?
- Zusammenfassung? - Besonders für deinen Anwendungsfall eines Papiers, das die Hauptpunkte eines Vortrags nochmals festhält.
- Hauptpunktepapier? - Für die Vortragszusammenfassung sicherlich geeignet.
- Memo? - Wird für zusammenfassendne Notizen im Anschluss an ein Gespräch vewendet. Ich finde aber, man könnte es auch verwenden für ein vorbereitetes Papier, das die Hauptpunkte eines Vortrags kurz und bündig festhält. Aber ich gebe zu, dass das keine gängige Verwendung ist.
- Stichpunktepapier? - Das wird öfter mal verwendet für solche Zwecke, auch in außeruniversitären Arbeitszusammenhängen. Das Bild, das vor meinem Auge entsteht ist: ein einzelnes Blatt, auf dem ein Vortragender seine wichtigsten Punkte nochmals schriftlich auflistet, und das er an die Zuhörer austeilt.

Comment: Eine Tischvorlage in den Gremien heißt aber genau deshalb so, weil sie den Mitgliedern eben nicht vorher zugesandt wird, sondern ihnen erst kurzfristig zu (oder während) einer Sitzung zur Verfügung gestellt wird.

Comment: @IQV  Da stimme ich dir zu. Wenigstens in der Theorie. In der Praxis habe ich es aber schon oft gesehen, dass Gemeinderäte die "Tischvorlagen" vorher mit der Post zugeschickt kriegen. Das sind ja schnell mal 20 Seiten engbedruckt, die kann man nicht während der Sitzung lesen. - Ich kenne auch Stadtverwaltungen, wo so etwas "Drucksache" genannt wird, obwohl es natürlich nicht mehr gedruckt wird sondern aus dem Kopierer kommt.

Comment: "Zusammenfassung" oder "schriftliche Zusammenfassung" passt dann wohl am besten, oder? Evtl. auch "Kurzzusammenfassung".

Comment: "Kurzzusammenfassung" klingt vertraut in meinen Ohren. Als hätte ich das an der Universität oder so schon gehört. Aber eigentlich ist es ein bisschen tautologisch: Die Zusammenfassung ist ja per se schon kurz (sonst wäre es keine Zusammenfassung). Also: Semantisch-logisch hätte ich ein Problem mit dem Word. Pragmatisch ist es aber wohl gut.

Comment: Ich würde das jetzt nicht tautologisch sehen, eher eine Steigerung von Zusammenfassung.

Comment: @student  Ja, so kann man es wohl auch sehen...

Comment: Thesenpapier hat einen bestimmten Inhalt und Funktion, eben keine Zusammenfassung sonder Grundlage zur weiteren Debatte/Diskussion; ist daher nur eine kleine Untergruppe der Handouts, und außerhalb seines natürlichen Habitats von Seminaren wohl ein sehr scheues Waldschratwesen. Ein Student wird beim Pro-Seminar-Referat zum Thesenpapier angehalten, ein Professor wird niemals ein solches zur Vorlesung an Studenten verteilen?

Comment: @LangLangC  Es gibt "Thesenpapiere" schon auch in anderen Institutionen; eigentlich in allen öffentlichen oder privaten größeren Einrichtungen, wo interne Dinge (Geschäftsstrategie, Organisationsentwicklung, Parkraumkonzept, was weiß ich) diskutiert werden. Vielleicht ist "Thesenpapier" nicht originär von dort, da aber viele Leute, die in solchen Organisationen arbeiten, vorher Hochschulseminare besucht haben, hätte das Waldschratwesen "Thesenpapier" jedenfalls reichlich Gelegenheit, durch diese Tür lexikalischer Prägung zu schlüpfen und sich dort anzusiedeln. Ein Wort-Migrant demnach.

Comment: Das mag sein. Hab da vielleicht ein schiefes Bild von weiten Teilen der westlichen Wirtschaftswildnis. Da Wikipedia aber ein ebenso queres Bild vom Thesenpapier zu zeichnen scheint, mir auch etwas anderes erzählt wurde als [zB hier, PDF](https://tu-dresden.de/gsw/slk/germanistik/al/ressourcen/dateien/dateien/thesenpapier) ist Google wieder schlau genug gewesen, meinen prinzipiellen Einwand als ersten Treffer zu empfehlen.

Answer (score 1):

Meiner Ansicht nach gibt es kein deutsches Wort, dass das englische *handout* wirklich allgemein abbildet. Solltest Du ein Universal-Wort für alle Zwecke benötigen, wirst Du um den Anglizismus nicht herumkommen.

Ansonsten würde ich empfehlen, für jeden konkreten Einzelfall das jeweils dafür passendste Wort zu verwenden - die [Liste von Christian Geiselmann](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/49711/23) ist dafür ein guter Ausgangspunkt.

Weitere Möglichkeiten, die mir einfallen, wären *Ausdrucke* oder - bei einer Universitätsvorlesung oder einem wissenschaftlichen Vortrag - *Skript*

Comment: Unter einem Skript hätte ich jetzt einen längeren Vorlesungsmitschrieb (evtl. mehrere hundert Seiten) verstanden (engl. "lecture notes"). Dies würde ich eigenlich nicht als Handout bezeichnen. Beim Handout scheint mir schon die Kürze des Dokumentes mit einzufließen.

Comment: @student Hängt ganz davon ab, ob es ein Skript für das gesamte Semester ist (das kann dann in der Tat 100+ Seiten haben) oder nur den Inhalt der Vorlesung an diesem Tag abbildet (das Wort "Vorlesung" ist leider mehrdeutig und bezeichnet sowohl die einzelne Unterrichtseinheit als auch die Unterrichtsreihe) oder ob es sich sowieso um einen Einzelvortrag handelt.

Comment: Script wäre dann ein anderer Anglizismus für einen Anglzismus, den man hier vermeiden will.

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli vielleicht habe ich da durch mein Studium eine verzerrte Wahrnehmung, aber ich empfinde Skript als zu geläufig, um es als Anglizismus wahrzunehmen. Ist es überhaupt einer? Man kann auch argumentieren, dass es die Kurzform von Manuskript ist, was zwar auch ein Fremdwort, aber lateinischer Herkunft, ist.

Comment: ich meine nur: ein paper, ein Papier, ein Skript oder ein script ist doch alles egal im Hinblick darauf, dass jamand einen Anglizismus mit einem deutschen Wort ersetzen will. Ich habe mit einem Skript kein Problem. Ich wäre sogar mit einem guten handout zufrieden. Aber jetzt zu etwas ganz abderem: der downvote oder gut deutsch das Herunterwählen kam tatsächlich von mir, war aber gar nicht beabsichtigt! Es muss beim runterscrollen, ähm, Herabfahren auf screen ... Bildschirm geschehen sein, sorry, eh entschuldigung. Wird gleich korrigiert, ich meine: wieder gut gemacht!

Comment: Ist leider nicht möglich. Also das ist anderen bei mir sicher auch schon passiert. Ganz klar ein Fall für die meta.

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli Du musst einfach nochmal den Downvote-Pfeil anklicken. *Nicht* das Downvote durch ein Upvote ausgleichen

Comment: Man braucht noch einen Edit, damit sich etwas geändert hat. Und Skript ist kein Anglizismus, beides kommt aus dem Latein *manu scriptum* und damit wären wir beim Manuskript (fehlt noch) ;)

Comment: @ Volker: Jetzt hat es geklappt.:) Übrigens bei uns hiess in den 70er Jahren noch paper. Also Papier wäre gar nicht schlecht, oder einfach Blatt?

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli Blatt? Und was machst Du, wenn es 2 oder gar 3  zusammengetackerte - äh, zusammengeheftklammerte (*grins*) - Blätter sind? ;-)

Comment: Halt das Beiblatt. Bei einem paper hat sich auch keiner gestört, wenn es 20 waren, man sprach trotzdem in der Einzahl.

Answer (score 1):

Da Handout im Englischen auch Almosen bezeichnen kann, halte ich **Handreichung**, für die ähnliches gilt, für am besten geeignet. Dass es auf ein längeres Dokument hinweist, sehe ich nicht so.

Answer (score 0):

Dann bleibt noch die Frage:

> Gibt es noch ein passenderes deutsches Wort, das den Anglizismus "Handout" im oben beschriebenen Gebrauch am besten erfasst.

*Welche Funktion hat das Handout?
Bevor du dein Handout verfasst, solltest du dir immer vor Augen führen, welchen Zweck das Paper hat. Klar: Es begleitet den Vortrag. Aber viel wichtiger: **Es dient der Orientierung deiner Zuhörer. Sie können deiner freien Rede so besser folgen, eigene Notizen machen und behalten das, was du erzählst, leichter.** Außerdem unterstützt das Handout die Nachbereitung deines Vortrages. All diese Funktionen solltest du im Hinterkopf haben, wenn du dich an das Handout setzt. Stell dir die simple Frage: Was würde mir dabei helfen, einem Vortrag besser folgen zu können?*

https://www.uniturm.de/magazin/organisation/das-perfekte-handout-1312

Da es für diesen Anglizismus keinen entsprechenden deutschen Ausdruck gibt, steht es dir frei, einen selber zu kreieren oder einen passenden Vergleich zu wählen!

Meine Vorschläge:

- Fahrplan
- Wegweiser
- Papier
- Zusammenfassung
  – und wie von Volker schon erwähnt: das Skript
  (so hiessen bei uns die Unterlagen des Dozenten)